# RHEL 6.5 - dependencies

Tags: dependencies, rhel6

I have problem with dependecies. Please, could you give me any advice how to solve it?

Error: Package: 1:perl-Package-Constants-0.02-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: perl-IO-Compress-Zlib-2.021-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: perl-Archive-Tar-1.58-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: perl-IO-Compress-Base-2.021-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: 1:perl-Compress-Raw-Zlib-2.021-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: rpm-build-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (local)

Error: Package: 1:perl-IO-Zlib-1.09-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

1. Error: Package: 1:perl-IO-Zlib-1.09-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

   - Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (local)
            * perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
2. Error: Package: perl-Compress-Zlib-2.021-136.el6.x86_64 (local)

   - Requires: perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
   - Installed: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6_6.1.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)
            perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6_6.1
   - Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-127.el6.x86_64 (local)
            perl = 4:5.10.1-127.el6

     - Available: 4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 (local)
          perl = 4:5.10.1-136.el6
3. Error: Package: rpm-build-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (local)

   - Requires: rpm = 4.8.0-37.el6

     - Installed: rpm-4.8.0-38.el6_6.x86_64 (@rhel-x86_64-server-6)

       - rpm = 4.8.0-38.el6_6
     - Available: rpm-4.8.0-37.el6.x86_64 (local)

       - rpm = 4.8.0-37.el6

Comment: ** yum repolist**

Loaded plugins: security 
repo id  -- repo name   -- status                                                                               
local -- local --  1 229 
repolist: 1 229

Comment: [root@qradarEventProcessor qradar]# yum update  

Loaded plugins: security  
Setting up Update Process 
No Packages marked for Update

Comment: I tried to downgrade package: # yum downgrade --skip-broken perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64. Result is: 

Packages skipped because of dependency problems: 
    4:perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 from local
    4:perl-libs-5.10.1-136.el6.i686 from rhel-x86_64-server-6